# Unzip single zipped file into parts?

Tags: file, unzip

I have a single file that is zipped. I want to unzip this, but I don't have enough space on the computer. Is there a way to unzip it in parts? For example, first I'd want to unzip the first quarter (or x GB), then stop, look at the resulting file, delete it, and then unzip the next part. The parts do not have to fit together perfectly to form a new file.

I'm using Windows.

EDIT
The  original pre-zipped file is only 1 file. This single file was zipped, and now I need to unzip it, but in parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's a text file:

I'm not sure how to do this natively in Windows, but this is very easy to do under unix. You can download [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) which will give you access to the unix tools that can do this.

Then you can do:

```
/cygdrive/c/yourDisk/
$ zcat yourFile.zip | sed -n 1,1000p > file1.txt
```

This will give you the first thousand lines in a file in c:\yourDisk\file1.txt

Comment: Thanks! I can move it to a unix machine and do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use your Windows Explorer to explore the zip file... it allows you to open subdirectories (folders) and for you to navigate anywhere within the zip as if it was a normal folder.

When you find something you want to view, either double click it, or drag it to another location in your drive. If you drag it, you will end up copying whatever you are dragging to a new location (say, your temporary work area). Note, copying is not the same as moving as the original compressed version will continue to exist within the zipped folder.

When you have finished with whatever you dragged out, you can delete it (the copy) and return to your original and pull out more data/files for inspection.

Look at my attached image... notice the directory path where I have the red arrow. It says I opened a file called myzipfile.zip (I did a right mouse button over the file and clicked Open With... and selected Windows Explorer).

[image: windows exploring zip example]

Comment: The  original pre-zipped file is only 1 file. There are no directories to explore. I need to split what was originally one file into multiple files.

Comment: What is the file type inside the zip? Meaning, is it a 'txt' 'doc' 'mp4' 'mp3' etc etc ? If its another zip file, then you should be able to slide and dice it. If its some other file, then best move it elsewhere where you have more room to play with it.